# ! Simulating a button click - dealing with objects/classes/events

Tags: events, button, click, wxpython

I have a python module abc.py which has numerous class and some class inherting from another classes. The entire file has classes that are connected to each other with objects/instantiation.

The function calls are all based off of GUI button clicks. So, functions get called in abc.py, when buttons are clicked.

I need to write a script which does exactly the same function of button clicking, but without me clicking on the actual GUI - you can imagine it automated.

The issue is, the button on the GUI, when clicked, an event is triggered and the button is associated with a function call "def button_press" which takes (self, event) as parameters.

How would I pass it self and event? I want to use the classes/functions in the module "abc.py" as is and also simulate the button click.. Could you give me some pointers on how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Create an appropriate event, fill it with your test data and call self.button_press(your_test_event), from within your gui.
2. As above but from outside your gui call, app.topframe..button_press(your_test_event),
3. If your event handler does not use any data from the event then if you def button_press(self, evt=None) you can do a or b without creating an event first,
4. you can use any one of the excellent python GUI Test tools available - some are listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#GUI_Testing_Tools).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look at wx.PostEvent to send events to a button. Or if you're using wxPython 2.9.2 or better, then you can use the new UIActionSimulator, which you can read about here:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/UIActionSimulator.html

I've heard a number of people who use [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) for GUI testing. There's also [COBRA](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CobraWinLDTP/4.0.0), which I keep seeing listed on the Tested in Python user's group as a tool for GUI testing, although I'm not entirely sure if you can use it on a wxPython app.